# Handlebars Template rendering template as text

Tags: javascript, template-engine, mustache, handlebars.js

I created a helper in Handlebars to help with logic, but my template parses the returned html as text rather than html.

I have a quiz results page that is rendered after the quiz is completed:

```
  <script id="quiz-result" type="text/x-handlebars-template">
        {{#each rounds}}
          {{round_end_result}}
        {{/each}}
        <div class="clear"></div>
  </script>
```

For each of the rounds, I use a helper to determine which template to render a round's result:

```
  Handlebars.registerHelper("round_end_result", function() {
    if (this.correct) {
      var source = '';
      if (this.guess == this.correct) {
        console.log("correct guess");
        var source = $("#round-end-correct").html();
      } else {
        var source = $("#round-end-wrong").html();
      }
      var template = Handlebars.compile(source);
      var context = this;
      var html = template(context);
      console.log(html);
      return html;
    } else {
      console.log("tie");
    }
  });
```

Here is a template that describes a correct round (let's take say it rendered the #round-end-correct template):

```
  <script id="round-end-correct" type="text/x-handlebars-template">
        <div></div>
  </script>
```

Here is what gets rendered:

```
<div></div>
```

Not as HTML, but as text. How do I get it to actually render the HTML as HTML, rather than text?

Answer (score 152, accepted):

I assume that unescaping in Handlebars works the same as in vanilla Mustache.
In that case use triple mustaches to unescape html, i,e: `{{{unescapedhtml}}}`, like:

```
<script id="quiz-result" type="text/x-handlebars-template">
    {{#each rounds}}
      {{{round_end_result}}}
    {{/each}}
    <div class="clear"></div>
```

for ref see: 
http://mustache.github.com/mustache.5.html

Comment: This method wasn't working for me when using registerBoundHelper with 2 parameters. But "return new Handlebars.SafeString(result);" worked for me.

Answer (score 20):

Geert-Jan's answers is correct but just for reference you can also set the result to "safe" directly inside the helper (code from handlebars.js wiki)

```
Handlebars.registerHelper('foo', function(text, url) { 
  text = Handlebars.Utils.escapeExpression(text);
  url = Handlebars.Utils.escapeExpression(url); 
  var result = '<a href="' + url + '">' + text + '</a>'; 
  return new Handlebars.SafeString(result); 
});
```

With that you can use regular double handlebars {{ }} and handlebars won't escape your expression.