# Passing HTML markup into handlebars

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, json

I have an unusual situation where a client would like to place a line break in a string that is passed to handlebars from a JSON object. I've tried escaping characters but it isn't rendered by the DOM unsurprisingly. Any suggestions?

---

```
"company": "Lorem adscs ireland <br/> marketed as iuhmdsf in Europe"
```

---

```
var products = Data;

var theTemplateScript = $("#product-template").html();

var theTemplate = Handlebars.compile (theTemplateScript);
$("#marketed-products .products").append (theTemplate(products));
```

---

```
{{#items}}
<li><span class="company">{{company}}</li>
{{/items}}
```

---

The output from the code above should look something like this

Lorem adscs ireland 
marketed as iuhmdsf in Europe

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Handlebars Template rendering template as text](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7168469/handlebars-template-rendering-template-as-text)

Answer (score 48, accepted):

Use triple brackets, like `{{{returnedHtml}}}`, in that case Handlebars will not escape the value.

i.e it will become:

```
{{#items}}
<li><span class="company">{{{company}}}</li>
{{/items}}
```

Comment: Yeah it was fine, I removed my comment right after I made it. My mistake.