# Handlebars.js pass html in expression

Tags: handlebars.js

Handlebar template

```
<div>
    {{contentText}}
</div>
```

JS

```
var contentText = {contentText: "<table><tr><td>Some Data<\/td><\/tr><\/table>"}
```

Handle bars render displays the HTML as string rather than rendering the HTML.

Where am I going wrong ?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Handlebars Template rendering template as text](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7168469/handlebars-template-rendering-template-as-text)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

From the [fine manual](http://handlebarsjs.com):

> Handlebars HTML-escapes values returned by a `{{expression}}`. If you don't want Handlebars to escape a value, use the "triple-stash", `{{{`.

So if you want to put `contentText` straight into the template as-is then you want:

```
<div>
    {{{contentText}}}
</div>
```

in your template.

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/ambiguous/f7LJ5/

Comment: was searching for this forever. Thanks that worked like a charm.