# Insert html in a handlebar template without escaping

Tags: javascript, handlebars.js

Is there a way to insert a string with html tags into a handlebars template without getting the tags escaped in the outcoming string?

template.js:

```
<p>{{content}}</p>
```

use the template

```
HBS.template({content: "<i>test</i> 123"})
```

actual outcome:

```
<p>&lt;i&gt;test&lt;/i&gt; 123</p>
```

expected result:

```
<p><i>test</i> 123</p>
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Handlebars Template rendering template as text](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7168469/handlebars-template-rendering-template-as-text)

Answer (score 504, accepted):

Try like

```
<p>{{{content}}}</p>
```

[official reference](https://handlebarsjs.com/guide/expressions.html#html-escaping):

> Handlebars HTML-escapes values returned by a `{{expression}}`. *If you
> don't want Handlebars to escape a value,* use the "triple-stash", **`{{{`**.

Comment: Honestly seems like the worst thing they could've chosen since it's hard to notice. Why not just something simple but visible like `{{ rawHtml expression }}`.

Comment: Agree with @danneu. No magic or cute shorthand, please. Explicit is better in the long run.

Comment: It is worth noticing that spaces also matters, so `{{{content}}}` != `{{{ content }}}`, second will not work. Be sure you do not include any spaces.

Answer (score 40):

In your template you must add triple mustaches like this. `<p>{{{content}}}</p>`

See [Official Reference](https://handlebarsjs.com/guide/expressions.html#html-escaping) for more information on that.

Answer (score 33):

According to the [Handlebars documentation](https://handlebarsjs.com/guide/expressions.html#html-escaping):

> If you don't want Handlebars to escape a value, use the "triple-stash", `{{{`

Pass the raw HTML to Handlebars template and get the raw HTML output by using triple brackets.

```
{{{foo}}}
```