# CKeditor outputs Html. How to format it for displaying properly, not just lame html?

Tags: javascript, html, css, meteor, ckeditor

I am using [CKeditor](http://ckeditor.com), and this is my code:

```
       ...othercode..


     <div class="input-field col s12">
                        <textarea id="textarea1" class="materialize-textarea"></textarea>
                        <label for="textarea1">Body of the Post</label>
                    </div>
                    <input type="submit" name="Submit" id="sub">
                </form>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    {{else}}
    <div>You are not logged in.</div>
    {{/if}}
    <script>
    CKEDITOR.replace('textarea1');
    </script>
```

In Javascript, I use the same id to extract the text from the textarea, because I have to save it to collection. (`Notice the handlebars.`)

When I do that, It returns the html code, and that is saved as a string inside collection, and the handlebar doesnt do anythign and displayed the same html, without giving meaning to the html tags, i.e., just lame html.

How can this be converted to string anywhere, so that, the {{body}} handlebar shows exactly how it was typed inide CKeditor, and not what the backend of ckeditor returns.

This is the output I want:

```
Okay

Okay

Okay
```

THis is the output I get:

```
<p>Okay</p>
<p>Okay</p>
<p>Okay</p>
```

Comment: Whay do you mean by `lame` html? could you post an example of the output and how you would like to be?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Insert html in a handlebar template without escaping](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20280601/insert-html-in-a-handlebar-template-without-escaping)

Comment: I edited the question. Check.

Comment: It is clearly not the duplicate of the question tagged.

Comment: @Abhi show the code you use to show the result please

Comment: Okay. Idk why but the three handlebar syntax works. Can you explain how?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You use triple braces in spacebars for this.

So your answer is

```
{{{body}}}
```

Comment: This doesn't solve the issue. See the edited question.

Comment: Then you need to be more clear. To properly escape HTML coming from a template helper or data call you use triple braces. 

So be clear, are you simply trying to capture the data as html or are you trying to output it? You have the output part answered because that's what people think you are asking.

Answer (score 1):

Try it

```
<script>
function myFunction() {
  var iframe = document.getElementById("myFrame");
  var elmnt = iframe.contentWindow.document.getElementsByTagName("H1")[0];
  elmnt.style.display = "none";
}
</script>
```