# How to allow html in template data for dynamic Sendgrid transactional template?

Tags: c#, sendgrid, sendgrid-api-v3, sendgrid-templates

Maybe I'm not seeing the obvious here. I'm using [this library](https://github.com/sendgrid/sendgrid-csharp) for sending mails. And I'm also using [transactional templates](https://sendgrid.com/docs/ui/sending-email/how-to-send-an-email-with-dynamic-transactional-templates/).

A quick code example:

```
var msg = new SendGridMessage {From = new EmailAddress("my@email.com")};
var personlization = new Personalization {Tos = new List<EmailAddress> {new EmailAddress("some@email.com")}};
dynamic t = new System.Dynamic.ExpandoObject();
t.firstname = "John";
t.lastname = "Doe";
t.message = "a <br/> line <br/> break";
msg.TemplateId = "abcdefg";
personlization.TemplateData = t;
msg.Personalizations = new List<Personalization> {personlization};

var response = await client.SendEmail(msg);
```

I can see how to add content manually, text or html by using the `htmlContent` prop, but in this case I'm using a transactional template.

In the example above, the email comes through html encoded instead of creating the line breaks, and I want the personalizations to be html. In addition, the template is html.

Answer (score 9):

The answer your looking for is [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20280656/886670), the issue is the template you are using

> Handlebars HTML-escapes values returned by a `{{expression}}`. *If you
>   don't want Handlebars to escape a value,* use the "triple-stash", **`{{{`**.