# How to shortcut a link we got from api?

Tags: angular

When I put this out on my html like this:

```
  <div class="description">
    {{playlist.description}}
  </div>
```

so `{{playlist.description}} =  The best of lofi hip hop and chill hop! In case this isn't enough, take a look at our 24/7 lofi hip hop <a href="https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=MCkTebktHVc">stream</a>`

And I want to put `<a></a>` into a word how can I do that?

Comment: You mean you have an HTML string from the API that you want to render without escaping the tags? [Insert html in a handlebar template without escaping](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20280601/insert-html-in-a-handlebar-template-without-escaping)

Comment: But you probably don't want to completely trust the HTML the API gives you e.g. in case it starts sending <script> tags.

Comment: Yes the API gave me that string but somehow `<a>` tag in that string didnt work. idk why

Comment: When you say doesn't work you mean it's been displayed on the page as `<a>` rather than a link? Yes, that's because `{{` escapes any content for display. If you really do trust the API as a source of valid HTML then you can use `{{{` as in the question I linked to. However you possibly should try and filter the HTML down to a set of safe tags first.

Comment: i tried to `{{{playlist.description}}}` but it giving me this error `Uncaught Error: Template parse errors:
Parser Error: Missing expected : at column 10 in [ {{{playlist.description}}} ]`

Comment: Oh OK, I don't know then sorry. The [handlebars documentation](https://handlebarsjs.com/guide/#html-escaping) says `{{{` is correct, and that [dots are allowed](https://handlebarsjs.com/guide/#nested-input-objects) to select properties, so that looks OK to me.

Comment: Yea don’t know how to make this work