# Handle HTML Escapes values in HandleBars JS

Tags: javascript, jquery, handlebars.js

Not sure how to handle this scenario where JSON response contains HTML escaped values that needs to be converted to proper HTML tags.

```
"description": "Lorem adscs ireland &lt;br/&gt; marketed as in Europe"
```

rendered as text -

```
Lorem adscs ireland <br/> marketed as in Europe
```

Is it possible to resolve this issue. Please suggest.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Handlebars Template rendering template as text](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7168469/handlebars-template-rendering-template-as-text)

Comment: Side note showing small template that does not work for you may help - so far looks like duplicate of regular "render unescaped HTML with handlebarJS" question.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `SafeString` to prevent handlbars from escaping the string.

```
Handlebars.registerHelper('link', function(text, url) {
  text = Handlebars.Utils.escapeExpression(text);
  url  = Handlebars.Utils.escapeExpression(url);

  var result = '<a href="' + url + '">' + text + '</a>';

  return new Handlebars.SafeString(result);
});
```

[Handlebars docs](http://handlebarsjs.com/) - I can't link to the section but it's called Html Escaping

Answer (score 0):

Perform a html decode function just before processing the string